# Does Camus show that all suicide is an evil?

Tags: existentialism, camus

Does Camus show that all suicide is an evil?

What if the the girl in *The Fall* is about to be captured, repeatedly raped, maimed and tortured?

Is it only the insane, or even weak, who would not choose that fate?

Comment: Welcome to Philosophy.SE. Recall that Camus said Sisyphus, who is condemned to an eternity of struggling against a stone, should be happy. He may well say the same of someone about to experience the sort of suffering you describe.

Comment: You can see [Suicide as a Response to Absurdity](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/camus/#SuiResAbs).